Ошибка 1064: "You have an error in your SQL syntax"
Я пробую вставить в таблицу значение переменной, которую я получаю от пользователя:
try:
    # create table
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        role = "user"
        version = 0
        dol = 0
        #insert_query = "INSERT INTO `DataBaseRegAndLog` ('user', 'pass', 'role', 'version', 'email', 'dol') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `DataBaseRegAndLog` ('user', 'pass', 'role', 'version', 'email', 'dol') VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (loginUser, passUser, role, version, emailUser, dol))
        connection.commit()

finally:
    connection.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print("Connection refused...")
    print(ex)

Но мне выдаёт ошибку 1064:
C:\Users\Demon\PycharmProjects\tg_DemonDostavka\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Demon\PycharmProjects\tg_DemonDostavka\main.py 
successfully connected...
####################
Connection refused...
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user', 'pass', 'role', 'version', 'email', 'dol') VALUES ('/reg', '/reg', 'user' at line 1")

Я пробовал сначала sql-команду прописать в отдельной переменной, но там выдаёт ошибку. Сейчас у меня получилось, что в одной строчке sql-команда и переменные.

Измените кавычки для имён полей на `
Символ ' используется для указания строк, например:
select `name`,'name' from shops

Amizon | name
Wild beer yes | name
Ozun | name
